# In D3, How to disable double click zoom conditionally?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In D3.js you can disable double click zoom with following snippet.

```
.on("dblclick.zoom", null);
```

In my scenario, there are `circles` in the `svg`, if you double click on the `svg` it should zoom in, but if you double click any of the `circle` elements, the zoom should be disabled.

I have one option which is

```
d3.select('svg').selectAll('image').on('dblclick', () => {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This works, but I can't go with this option with my current setup.

I want to know if there is any way I can check a condition and then disable zoom with something like this -

```
on("dblclick.zoom", () => {
  if (event.target.localName == 'circle') {
    // disable zoom
  } else {
    // enable zoom
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

you can find fiddle where I have reproduced my problem - https://jsfiddle.net/bhnbhushan/dnzpyjx0/2/

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two options. You can do what you suggested which was to utilize event delegation check if the `event.target` is a `circle` element. Just be aware in `d3` you may need to hook into [`d3.event`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#d3_event) instead to access the `target`.

`d3.zoom` also provides a way to filter with the [`zoom.filter`](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_filter) which similarly you can pass in the condition you want to hook into i.e. checking if `d3.event.target` is a `circle`.

EDIT: It sounds like you are using d3.v3 which from the API doesn't support as much to handle these use cases. I highly suggest upgrading.

Comment: `zoom.filter` is best option but its not available in my `d3.js` version, its  `3.5.17`, and event delegation is not working as I'm handling double click event with React.

Comment: Oh interesting do you mind posting the full code or a working example? Would make it easier to help

Comment: Hi, I have reproduced my problem in this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/bhnbhushan/dnzpyjx0/2/

Comment: Hey took a look and played around. So one thing to be aware of is the dblClick in React may not sync with the D3 events because you're selecting the events and applying it via `d3` selectors so just as equally you would need to select the `circle` svgs with `d3`. However I think the larger issue is (and I could be wrong) is I don't think d3.v3 offers a way to handle this? You may need to upgrade :(

Comment: I went ahead by re writing event listener with D3 and stopping propogation works there. it's doing what I want but I don't know what else I broke, will know after regression tests. anyways thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do the same thing you did with your images? You can use your custom code with stopPropagation:

```
d3.select('svg').selectAll('circle').on('dblclick', () => {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // your code here
});
```

This will allow you to harness double click you want without propagating the double click to the svg.

Answer (score 0):

Aug's answer pointed me in the right direction but just in case someone needed more detail here's how I resolved my issue. It

I am already using double click events for other user needs. So there are specific instances in which I do not want the double click zoom to occur. This code worked for me in d3 version 5.15.x

```
D3.select('svg')
      .call(D3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([-5, 8])
        .extent([[0, 0], [300, 300]])
        .on('zoom', () => {

          D3.selectAll('g')
            .attr('transform', D3.event.transform);

          this.updateAfterInit(this.root);

        })
        .filter(() => {


          const foundNode = this.N.findNodeByID(D3.event.srcElement.id.split('_')[1])
          if ( !!foundNode && D3.event.type === 'dblclick' && foundNode.data.type === 'SearchRelationspec') {
            return false;
          } else {
            return !D3.event.target.classList.contains('drawarea') && D3.event.type === 'dblclick';
          }
        })
```